# How to attach existing privacy policy to IAM role via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I need to create a new IAM role via Terraform. The role should have a policy that is predefined in AWS (AmazonSSMFullAccess), but I cannot find anywhere how should I add a policy that is already created.
Code template should look like this:

```
    resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
      name                 = var.name
      assume_role_policy   = var.assume_role_policy
      max_session_duration = var.max_session_duration
      description          = var.description
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_policy" {
      policy_arn = var.policy_to_attach
      role       = aws_iam_role.role.name
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an existing aws policy, you can directly copy its arn from the console. Then simply paste the arn as the policy_arn parameter. In your case:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_policy" {
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMFullAccess"
    role       = aws_iam_role.role.name
}
```

To make it even more safe, you could first import the policy using [a datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy) :

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
    arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMFullAccess"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_policy" {
    policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.example.arn
    role       = aws_iam_role.role.name
}
```

EDIT: the datasource can also be summoned by name:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "test" {
  name = "AmazonSSMFullAccess"
}
```

As said in the comments, a datasource will be helpful to make terraform check that you can find and read the given policy before it tries to do anything else.

Comment: How is that data source helpful when you are referring to it by the ARN and then using the output ARN into the resource?

Comment: First, you can use the policy name if you prefer (pass `name` to the datasource instead of `arn`).
But more importantly, this will make terraform check that the policy actually exist, and can be found. It's usually helpful to have terraform fail at this early stage if you make a typo in the name, if the policy doesn't exist anymore, or if you don't have access to it for instance.
As a general rule of thumb: use datasource for every external resource you intend to use, wether it's an account, a policy...etc